# how to receive streaming data from flask application in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, streaming, flask

I want to receive streaming data from flask application in angularjs. Previously, I was making hundreds of $http calls from browser, and was appending their responses to a single variable in angularjs which was updating the HTML automatically every time it received a response from one of those AJAX calls. Now I want to move all that logic to backend, thus want to have a single HTTP call which will receive streaming data from flask application, and it is expected that HTML will be updated every time a streaming response is received at front end. How can I achieve that?

BTW, I leaned how to stream data from flask application to front end. But I want to know how should I receive it in angularjs.

Answer (score 0):

May be I'm not understanding your problem correctly, but from the gist of it I think you need to look into [web-sockets](https://www.google.no/search?q=web%20sockets) to get streaming up and running. [Implementing sockets in AngularJS](https://github.com/btford/angular-socket-io-seed)

Comment: Hi Kenneth, actually I am not using socket at backend. All I am doing is streaming some data to front end [(Streaming in Flask)](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/streaming/). But I am not aware of "how to read streaming data in angularjs (or in JQuery or even in Javascript)".

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer showing how to stream data from flask to the frontend and processing the stream-events in javascript.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13388915/649698

This helped me a lot.