# How to, with Flask, return several templates as the task is going?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I have a Flask server, and something like that:

```
@app.route("/page", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def page():
    is_working = False
    if (request.method == 'POST'):
        is_working = True
        do_long_task()
        is_working = False
    return render_template('page.html', is_working)
```

*do_long_task* is a process that can took some time. I want to alter the template considering if the process is running or not. With the example above the server simply wait for *do_long_task()* to finish to render the template. I ideally would like something like this:

```
@app.route("/page", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def page():
    is_working = False
    if (request.method == 'POST'):
        is_working = True
        render_template('page.html', is_working)
        do_long_task()
        is_working = False
        render_template('page.html', is_working)
```

But this won't work because the template once rendered must be returned (and thus *page* must finish) to be taken into account.

How can I do that ?

Comment: @Sergey's answer seems to address your problem, but i'll rather use JavaScript to fetch the data asynchronously.

Comment: How can you do that? Do you make Flask and Javascript communicate? How? If you mean work only with Javascript, that is not possible as do_long_task is something already implemented in Python and too big to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it is to use Flask [Streaming](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/streaming/). This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13388915/6682517) provides several examples how to do it. Note that it is not *rerendering* the page but sending additional data which need to be inserted on client side.