# Flask+AJAX+Jquery+JINJA to dynamically update HTML Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, flask, jinja2

I want to display the Port status dynamically. I don't want to reload the page to see a new value. I know how to get the Port status in Python(using `uiApi()`). Right now I render a template with the value and show the values in HTML table. How can I continually update the table with a value from Flask? I have the AJAX and jquery available.

The Flask Code is give below:

```
    @app.route('/')
    def show_auth():
       tData = uiApi()
       ..

       return render_template('show_auth.html', tMain=tData)
```

The {{field}} in The HTML file 'show_auth.html' below should be dynamically updated:

```
<form   action="{{ url_for('submit_token') }}" method=post>
  <div id="Main" class="tabcontent" style="display:block" >
    <div class="PanelWrapper" >
      <div class="pageTitle">WAN</div>
      <div class="layout">
        <div class="col">
          <table frame="void" rules="none">
            <tbody>
              {%for key, field in tMain.items() %}
              <tr>
                <td class="attrLabel" valign="middle" nowrap>{{key}}</td>
                <td class="attrLabel" valign="middle">:&nbsp;</td>
                <td>{{field}}</td>
              </tr>
              {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
...
....
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need two things : A route for an AJAX request that will return your data formatted as JSON (should be quite easy to do with Flask's `jsonify` function).

Once you have that route setup, you need to call it using an AJAX call. Using jQuery it feels painless (but you can do it with vanilla JS too).

```js
<script>
    $SCRIPT_ROOT = {{ request.script_root|tojson|safe }};
    (function(){
        $.getJSON(
            $SCRIPT_ROOT+"/_stuff", // Your AJAX route here
            function(data) {
                // Update the value in your table here
            }
        );
        setTimeout(arguments.callee, 10000);
    })();
</script>
```

In the snippet above you will need to specify the path of your AJAX route, and do things with the `data` value. For a quick test you can simply `console.log(data)` and check if the returned data are good.

Note that the above snippets uses an anonymous function, and will fetch your data every 10 seconds (10000 ms).

I hope that will help

Documentation :
[Ajax with Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/jquery/)
[jQuery.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)

Comment: The answer is really useful and working fine. Had to combine Depado's answer here [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15721679/update-and-render-a-value-from-flask-periodically to complete my need. Thanks Depado!