# How to trigger warning when face is not recognized?

Tags: python, opencv

This is code for detecting a face.

I want that whenever the face is recognized, a rectangle is shown on the face image, and that's fine, but whenever the face is not recognized, no rectangle is shown on the face image, and some message is printed.

```
import cv2
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('C:/Users/320052863/PycharmProjects/trial/venv/Lib/site-packages/cv2/data/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('C:/Users/320052863/PycharmProjects/trial/venv/Lib/site-packages/cv2/data/haarcascade_eye.xml')
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while 1:

    ret, img = cap.read() 
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)

    for (x,y,w,h) in faces: 
        re = cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,255,0),2)
        if 're' in locals():
            print('abhishek')
        else:
            print('gupta')
        roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w] 
        roi_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    cv2.imshow('Abhishek',img)

    # Wait for Esc key to stop
    k = cv2.waitKey(30)
    if k == 13:
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Can you elaborate: What do you mean by recognised? recognised as a face or recognised asa specific person?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that if, in your script, after your line:

```
faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
```

you insert the following line, it will warn if no faces have been detected:

```
if len(faces) == 0:
    print "No faces found"
```

Comment: I want to display that message in webpage. how can i do using flask?

Comment: @AbhishekGupta Firstly, please give feedback on whether the submitted solution works for you.

Comment: But i wanna do that message show on webpage as a pop-up message.

Comment: @AbhishekGupta Ok, great, please accept the answer and/or vote it as useful, and then I can give you further tips.

Comment: Actually,I am new user. I do not more than 15 reputation.That's why i can not give the vote.

Comment: @AbhishekGupta Thanks, understood. One possible approach is instead of just printing as above, you write the result to a small text file that can be read by the program that does the popup display in Flask. Please look at this stackexchange question, which should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15721679/update-and-render-a-value-from-flask-periodically