# Carry out realtime updates over Flask cache or POST request changes

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

The concepts of webhooks are quite simple, yet I am here for some guidance on how a realtime change in POST request is handled.
Consider a webhook program in FLASK:

```
@app.route('/webhook', methods = ['POST'])
def webhook():
    data = json.loads(request.data)
    
    return data
```

Such a program will easy return a json POST request. And result will look like this:

```
{
"passphrase": "SkZSV1YwZz0=",
"timenow": "2021-09-15T21:18:00Z",
"item": "apple",
"quantity": "50",
"account": "9999"
}
```

Now I have successfully read in the webhook data. Next step is to do something with the data.
Say  I would like to search my database `'df'` for `item: apple` and return the price.

```
def get_item_price(df, item_name):
    # Returns price by filtering df.
    df = df[df['name'] == item_name]
    df.reset_index(inplace = True)
    price = df['price']
    return price
```

So, `price_of_item = get_item_price(df, item_name)` can now be used. But since webhook is a **POST** request I am using cache to access values from other routes.

```
cache.set("price_data", price_of_item )
```

I can get the price of the apple by calling cache from another route. Say:

```
@app.route("/index")
def index():
    price_data_recieved= cache.get("price_data")

    # do some stuff based on price_data_recieved, and call a api
    
    return index_template.format(message = price_of_item)

index_template = """
    <div> the price of apple is: {price_data_recieved}{some_other_stuff} </div>
    """
```

However this is not real time, I need to reload the browser every time. Can I make changes to this such that as a new POST request changes my `index` route output as well. I assume its like a ping to `/index` and initiate a task.

Resources explored unsuccessfully:

1. [Make a POST request while redirecting in flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15473626/make-a-post-request-while-redirecting-in-flask)
2. [Display data streamed from a Flask view as it updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31948285/display-data-streamed-from-a-flask-view-as-it-updates)
3. [Update and render a value from Flask periodically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15721679/update-and-render-a-value-from-flask-periodically)
4. [Execute a function after Flask returns response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48994440/execute-a-function-after-flask-returns-response)

Comment: This sounds like it would be best handled by your front end with some JavaScript to update the value, instead of reloading the entire page.

Comment: JS will not help if i call an api in /index route

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the question because I don't see how calling an API in `index` would preclude updating values with JavaScript.

Comment: values in `index` only gets updated only if its loaded, i dont see how i can get the values without loading `index`. Also not an expert in JS

Answer (score 0):

I am going with While Loop to check if cache values have changed from the previous stored once for now, until a better method is available.