# how to use a byte stream to do parsing with python-opencv

Tags: python, opencv, flask, base64, artificial-intelligence

I have a flask server in python that receives a string of bytes in base64 (they are video frames) constant, these are saved in a variable, what I want is to be able to access that stream with opencv videocapture()
*to be able to use them in a real-time analysis* and show in the html
the question would be how to analyze this flow of video frames in real time.

```python
# Importing the relevant libraries
import asyncio
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
from flask import Response
import cv2
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_sock import Sock
import time
import numpy as np
import base64

app = Flask(__name__)
sock = Sock(app)

@sock.route('/')
def socket():
    while True:
        data = ws.receive() #---->data in  base64 frames
        img=base64.b64decode((data))
        if img is not None: 
            img = cv2.imdecode(np.frombuffer(img, dtype=np.byte), flags=cv2.IMREAD_COLOR) 
            #img is a numpy.ndarray

#I would like to be able to use this byte stream here below.**

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(img) #------> put here the stream frame 
face_detector = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades +
     "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")
def generate():
     while True:
          ret, frame = cap.read()
          if ret:
               gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
               faces = face_detector.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
               for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
                    cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
               (flag, encodedImage) = cv2.imencode(".jpg", frame)
               if not flag:
                    continue
               yield(b'--frame\r\n' b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' +
                    bytearray(encodedImage) + b'\r\n')
@app.route("/")
def index():
     return render_template("index.html")
@app.route("/video_feed")
def video_feed():
     return Response(generate(),
          mimetype = "multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame")
if __name__ == "__main__":
     app.run(debug=False)
cap.release()
```

[Illustrative image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqIOD.png)

**thank you!**

Comment: b'\r\n' to  '\r\n'

Comment: Did you check this similar question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/24703421/18667225