# How to replace instead of add text by Python (Flask) Streaming

Tags: python, web-services, flask

I've got a simple flask web-service that runs AI training and responds with a stream of HTML text. Code for learning looks like this:

```
@app.route('/learn')
def learn():
    def learn():
    yield 'Prepare for learning...<br>'

    # PREPARE MODEL

    yield 'Learning started...<br>'
    for i in range(100):

        # TRAIN A LITTLE

        yield i.__str__() + '%<br>'
return Response(learn(), mimetype='text/html')
```

It works, but it adds every new text to previous one and I would like to replace text with a new one. So, right now output is like this:

```
Prepare for learning...
Learning started...
0%  
1%
2%
3%
4%
5%
......
```

I would like to have:

```
0%
```

and then:

```
1%
```

and so on...
Is it possible? How to do this?
Standard solutions that work with print, like \r at the end, doesn't work in this case.

Comment: Not related, but you should never call double-underscore methods directly. Instead of `i.__str__()` you should just do `str(i)`.

Comment: \r or end='' doesn't work here.