# How to display the tqdm progress rate on html page?

Tags: python, pandas, flask, progress-bar, tqdm

I am processing a pandas dataframe on the server-side which takes a pretty much good amount of time. It's very easy to display the progress of the task on the server-side (on the terminal) using tqdm. Like following code snippet:

```
def item_class_phen_pred(df, dataset_name):
    
    predicted_class_name = []
    sentence = []

    tokenizer, device, model, reverse_dict = dispatch_models(dataset_name)
    for i, row in tqdm(df.iterrows(), total=df.shape[0]):
        _, _, predicted_class = predict(row["Comment"], model, tokenizer, device)
        sentence.append(row["Comment"])

        for key, val in reverse_dict.items():
            if key == predicted_class:
                predicted_class = val
                predicted_class_name.append(predicted_class)
                break

    return predicted_class_name, sentence
```

Now, I want to display the progress rate on the client-side. Is it possible to store the progress of the task in a variable dynamically and pass it to the client-side. For tqdm, we don't need to anything, we can just pass the iterable to display the progress. But what I need to do if I want to pass the progress rate on the client-side?

For example, like below?

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response
import time, math
from tqdm import tqdm

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/content') # render the content a url differnt from index
def content():
    def inner():
        # simulate a long process to watch
        for i in tqdm(range(100)):
            time.sleep(1)
            # this value should be inserted into an HTML template
            yield str(i) 
    return Response(inner(), mimetype='text/html')

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

template code:

```
<div>
  <iframe frameborder="0" noresize="noresize" 
        style='background: transparent; width: 100%;  height:100%;' 
        src="{{ url_for('content')}}">   
 </iframe>
</div>
```

I found the above example in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64974111/5920567).

I am using flask on the server-side. Any help would be highly appreciated.