# get stdout of a python script to flask website with flask

Tags: html, python-3.x, flask, subprocess

I'd like to capture the output of a long running, but verbose script (pytest at the moment) and print the progress on a webpage. I'm facing two problems here

First: I need to asynchronously run the script and capture the output while it's still running. I found that pytest has the [`--capture=tee-sys`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.4.x/how-to/capture-stdout-stderr.html#setting-capturing-methods-or-disabling-capturing) flag, that i suppose is for this purpose, but I couldn't find out how that works.

A more general approach would be to use [`subprocess.Popen`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/636570/12925896) that seems to handle the asynchronous part already and output can be piped. However if I capture with `Popen.communicat()` I either block the thread until the process is finished and I can't live update, or I have to continuously catch the `TimeoutExpired` exception and re-initiate communication, what feels like a workaround, but would probably work. But is there an easier way to achieve this?

Second: I need to update the frontend without receiving a request. At first I even thought having a terminal style output would be cool and found stuff like [ttyd](https://github.com/tsl0922/ttyd), but that seems overkill and, if I'm not mistaken, would allow a user to input into the terminal, what I don't want. Now I also found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64974111/12925896), that suggests using an iframe and the `stream_template_context()` in the [flask documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/patterns/streaming/), however if I'm not mistaken in both cases it seems like I would need to build a valid html page on the run with the collected data from the subprocess and that feels prone to errors. I also found [flask-socketio](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), what I'd like to avoid, because the the falsk server is supposed to run on a custom linux and I'd need to add this module first. That should be doable in the end, but if there is an easier way I'd prefer that. Polling from a javascript in the frontend is an option I considered, but that looks like a workaround again. What would best practice here?

For both parts I'm happy about more resources to read about best practices etc.

after a bit more research I've got a minimal working example like this:

```py
from flask import Flask, Response, render_template
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/content')
def content():
    # start subprocess
    def inner():
        # proc = Popen(['/usr/local/bin/pytest', 'test1.py'], stdout=PIPE)
        with Popen(['/usr/local/bin/pytest', 'test1.py'], stdout=PIPE) as proc:
            while proc.poll() is None:
                line = proc.stdout.readline()
                # yield line.decode() + '<br/>\n'
                yield str(line) + '<br/>\n'

    return Response(inner(), mimetype='text/html')

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('test.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Where `test.py` just defines a series of test functions that each sleep
a second and `assert True` just to get a desired sample output,
and a `test.html`:

```html
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <iframe frameborder="1" 
                width="52%"
                height="500px"
                style='background: transparent;' 
                src="{{ url_for('content')}}">
        </iframe>
    </div>
</body>
```

However, the [subprocess documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) states, that using `proc.stdout.readline()` like this is discouraged, as it can deadlock the child process.
Moreover, I sometimes get a few, sometimes a lot of empty lines after the child process terminates. I use the `str(line)` to make them visible, as the `b''` from the bytes-string is there.
Any ideas on where to go from here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found two solutions to this, one I really like, so I'm going to share.

But first: I think I misunderstood the warning about not using `Popen.stdout.read()` in the [subprocess documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html). I only use the `readline` I should be fine, as the call should return in any case. (Please correct me if I'm wrong here, as the whole answer is based upon the assumption, that `readline` will not deadlock where `read` would.)

First solution: modifying [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64974111/12925896).
The `<iframe>` isn't actually needed, Flask can stream data into a `<div>`. The html looks like this:

```html
<p>Test Output</p>

<div id="output">
    {% if data %}
        {% for item in data %}
            {{ item }}<br />
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

The `{% if data %}` is optional. I used it to be able to load the page with an empty `<div>` and on a button press reload the site and provide `data` to fill the `<div>`

The python part looks like this:

```py
from flask import Response, stream_template
from subproces import Popen, PIPE

@app.route('/')
def stream() -> Response:
    """stream data to template"""
    def update(task: str | list[str]):
        """update the stream data"""
        with Popen(task, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE) as proc:
            while proc.poll() is None:
                line = proc.stdout.readline()
                log.info(line.decode())
                yield line.decode()
            while (line := proc.stdout.readline()) != b'':
                log.info(line.decode())
                yield line.decode()
            err = proc.stderr.read() # risk of deadlock
            # could be replaced by while readline as above
            if err != b'':
                log.warning("additionional stderr produced while running tests: %s", err.decode())
               
    return Response(
        stream_template('index.html.jinja',
                        data=update(['/usr/local/bin/pytest', 'dummytest.py'])))
```

I had to add the 2nd while loop after `proc.poll()` returned because I kept missing the last lines of data. But I would rather not use the 2nd while loop alone because that would risk breaking if a line was empty (shouldn't happen because the newline char should always be there).

The 2nd solution was basically [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71624720/12925896) utilizing the `EventSource`. I was hesitant to try this as I'm not as fluent in javascript, but in the end this worked like a charm. I added an event handler on a button, that prevented the forms `post` to the server, but manually opened the EventSource. The html looks like this:

```html
<div id="output"></div>


<p><form action="/action" method="post" role="form" id="testsForm">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Run Test</button>
</form></p>
    
<script type="text/javascript">
    (() => {
        'use strict'
        const form = document.getElementById("testsForm")
        form.addEventListener('submit', event => {
            event.preventDefault()
            var target = document.getElementById("output")
            var update = new EventSource("/action/stream")

            update.onmessage = function(e) {
                if (e.data == "close") {
                    update.close();
                } else {
                    target.innerHTML += (e.data + '<br/>');
                }
            };
        }, false)
    })()
</script>
```

The `action` and `method` in the form might be completely optional because the form never propagates to the backend. (This is using [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) classes, if someone wants to recreate this)

The python for this looks like this:

```py
from flask import Response
from subproces import Popen, PIPE

@app.route("/action/stream")
def stream() -> Response:
    """open event stream to client"""
    def update(task: str | list[str]):
        """update the event stream data"""
        with Popen(task, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE) as proc:
            log.info("opened subprocess for async task communication")
            while proc.poll() is None:
                line = proc.stdout.readline()
                log.info(line.decode().rstrip())
                # the '\n\n' is needed for termination in th frontend 
                # the stream handling (especially closing) will break without it
                yield 'data: ' + line.decode() + "\n\n"
            while (line := proc.stdout.readline()) != b'':
                log.info(line.decode())
                yield 'data: ' + line.decode() + "\n\n"
            err = proc.stderr.read() # risk of deadlock
            if err != b'':
                log.warning("additionional stderr produced while running script: %s", err.decode())
                
        yield "data: close\n\n"

    return Response(update(['/usr/local/bin/pytest', 'dummytest.py']), mimetype="text/event-stream")
```

The big plus for this solution is, that the website does not need to reload to stream the data. I have an empty box and when the button is pressed, the output of the script will appear on the screen. ([I even found some styling to make it look like an old school monitor](https://css-tricks.com/old-timey-terminal-styling/))

In terms of longer communication: I tested both versions with a 10-minute timeout in one test in the pytest script, and both worked without problem.

There might even be [another solution to this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31951077/12925896), but I never tried this as I don't quite understand it. I might be in the future, if the 2nd solution is not enough for some reason.