# Flask and jQuery - "onMessage" event not being called

Tags: python, flask, streaming

I'm working on a web interface for a project and need to plot a realtime chart with some data I'll get from an API I'm building. The API runs on http://SERVER_IP:5000/signal and my web interface on http://SERVER_IP:80/, both of them with Flask.

I was having CORS issues at the very beginning and then found out about [Flask-CORS](https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). I tried to implement that and now I'm getting no errors on the browser console, but no messages either! I've added some console messages for debugging, but it doesn't seem alright.

On my dashboard, I try to reach the API with the following code:

```js
const source = new EventSource("http://SERVER_IP:5000/signal", {withCredentials: true});

    console.log ("Things started!!!");

    source.onmessage = function (event) {
        console.log ("An event's just happened");
        // parse data and do stuff
    }
```

and in my API, I set Flask-CORS like this:

```py
self.__cors = CORS(self.__app, supports_credentials = True)
```

and the route like this:

```py
    @self.__app.route('/signal')
    def get_signal():

        import json

        def get_data():
            while True:            
                json_data = json.dumps(...)
                yield "{}\n\n".format(json_data)
                time.sleep(1)

        return Response(get_data(), mimetype='text/event-stream')
```

Then, when I open my web browser and open console, I can see the "Things started!!!" message, but no "An event's just happened" and no data on the chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was malforming my response. As I found out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12232304/how-to-implement-server-push-in-flask-framework), my "get_data" method should yield "data: ...", so after I added the "data: " after my data, things started to work pretty well.