# Send message to front end when Flask development server reloads

Tags: python, flask

I want to send a server send event to update the front end when a server reload happens. I know that you can auto-reload Flask by setting `FLASK_ENV=development`. Is there a callback like "onServerReload" that is called before or after a server refresh?

Comment: What does "update the front end" mean?

Comment: Receiving the server send event and refresh the HTML page.

Comment: See this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12232304/how-to-implement-server-push-in-flask-framework). It goes over how to send events from the server. Reloading on the client side is easy with javascript.

Comment: yeah, the push is not the problem, but the event from the server side. the link itself is useful once I have the event

Comment: I see. Have you tried [before_first_request](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Flask.before_first_request)? I'm not sure how it interacts with debug enabled, but from the docs, it sounds like it will work.

Comment: Thx for the suggestion. The method gets only called at client(browser) side request. So it does not get called when (auto-)reloading.

Answer (score 2):

Not really a solution, but too long for a comment...

Flask actually uses Werkzeug's reloader.  Here's where that phrase `* Detected change in '/chat/app.py', reloading` is printed out: [werkzeug/_reloader.py](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/648889f430f37ac49ee2f17c57e19f951049f9ad/src/werkzeug/_reloader.py#L187-L193)

The idea of having a hook for this, seems to have been discussed long ago in [issue 14](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/pull/14) and [issue 220](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/issues/220) but was never implemented.  The argument seems to be that when the application is actually reloaded, the entirety is run again, so:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
print ('I have been reloaded')
# Rest of file
```

On reload results in:

```
 * Detected change in '/chat/app.py', reloading
 * Restarting with stat
I have been reloaded
```

You could possibly put some code here which sends something to the stream, and wrap it in an `if` clause to make sure it only runs in dev.  How to actually implement that probably depends on what you've already got.

---

I cloned this repo: [github.com/jakubroztocil/chat](https://github.com/jakubroztocil/chat) which is a basic implementation of SSE with redis pub/sub as a broker, and made it look like:

```
red = redis.StrictRedis(host='redis')
# This will happen on init
red.publish('chat','Just Reloaded')
```

However the problem I came to was that when I published the 'Just Reloaded' message, because the app is in a state of reload, there are no subscribers to that channel (The subscription happens in the `event_stream()` function which is called when someone hits the `/stream` route.)

If you activate the reloader by saving a change to the code, and watch the browser's network tab you'll see the first stream close, and within a few seconds another stream opens to the same endpoint.  The publish command happened inbetween these points, so never reached the frontend.  This is a redis limitation I understand.

A workaround for this might be to have a dedicated flask server which handles just the event stream, and subscribes to a redis channel which the in-development apps also can publish to.  Then the in-development apps connect to that stream from their frontend, and on a code-reload the subscription doesn't cut out because it's being served by a dedicated flask instance.  The browser may complain if each server is accessed on a different port though.

Comment: So basically a frontend reloader wouldn't work this way, because of a lack of connection between the browser tab an the new reloaded server..... 

I guess the a 'server shut down' must be registered and a tab refresh would then try to connect to the new server (mayber with a time out)

Comment: Javascripts `EventStream` as implemented in the linked repo automatically reconnects to the `stream/` endpoint, as soon as the server reloads.  No need for a tab refresh.  The problem in this implementation is that when the `publish` command runs in my python example, the previous server is dead, but it's not yet serving the new `/stream` endpoint.  Seconds later it does and the client connects, but due to the way redis pub/sub works, the client will never see the published message, because it wasn't subscribed when that was published.

Answer (score 2):

After some research to flask `werkzeug/_reloader.py: ReloaderLoop.restart_with_reloader` at line 160. I find it uses `os.environ["WERKZEUG_RUN_MAIN"]` to check current process is whether monitor process or main server process. Once reload event is triggered, `trigger_reload` will be called, and simply call `sys.exit(3)`.

So here is my way out, in development mode:

```
def main():
    if os.environ.get("WERKZEUG_RUN_MAIN") == "true":
        # If we want to do something **ONLY WHEN** true main serve process is started
        do_something_only_when_real_server_process_started()

    try:
        app.run(debug=True)
    except SystemExit:
        do_something_when_reload_triggered_before_process_exit() # <-- 
        sys.exit(3) # see werkzeug/_reloader.py line 184
```