# Redis publish doesn't work in a Flask route

Tags: python, flask, redis

I have a Redis client in the *cache* file:

```py
from redis import Redis

client = Redis(host='0.0.0.0', port=6379, db=0)
```

That I use to subscribe in the *task* file:

```py
from cache import client

pubsub = client.pubsub()

def show(message):
    print(message.get('data'))

pubsub.subscribe(**{'msg': show})
```

Then in a Flask route in the *server* file I publish a message in the channel **msg**:

```py
from cache import client

client.publish(
    'msg',
    '( :'
)
```

But when I make a request to the route, nothing is published, or it is but nothing is shown. I have already try to see the log, read the [documentation](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py#publish--subscribe), use the [execute command](https://redis-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#redis.Redis.execute_command), looked a similar [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12232304/how-to-implement-server-push-in-flask-framework), etc, but nothing worked. Here's the [code](https://github.com/Sphinxs/Events/) to a more detailed context. Any tips?

Obs: As you can see in the code on the Github repository, the subscribe and the publish are in different threads

Comment: As `subscribe` method docs says: Channels supplied as keyword arguments expect
        a channel name as the key and a callable as the value. A channel's
        callable will be invoked automatically when a message is received on
        that channel **rather than producing a message via listen() or
        get_message()`**.

Comment: At first, to make sure core code works, please use `pubsub.subscribe('msg')`.

Comment: Also note, that `**{'msg': show}` is equivalent of just passing kwargs as `msg=show`.

Comment: Yes, the core code runs, if I publish at the line after the subscribe. I'm using objects because I'm gonna receive them in a request, but thanks for remember ( :

Comment: If it runs, that you can switch back to your old solution, but mind that `get_message` would be blocked forever. After removing it and writing whole logic in `show`, everything will work.

Comment: No, no, I mean it runs if I place the `publish` manually after the `subscribe` declaration, but it still doesn't work on the Flask route.

Comment: I figured out that if I run the Flask application with the `threaded` option set to `True`, then the messages are published in the channel, through the Flask route. I'm trying to understand why it happens (the [documentation](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/0.16.x/serving/#werkzeug.serving.run_simple) doesn't mention nothing about this behavior) and how to avoid a large amount of threads, once each request will be handle in a different thread.

Comment: What flask version are you running? threaded=True is default from 1.0.0

Comment: 1.1.1 Do you know about the behavior with `threaded = False`?

Comment: Yes, requests are handled one at a time if set to `False`.

Comment: Yes, but I don't understand how it breaks the publisher... anyways, thanks ( :